# EmberJs Change name to belongsTo property in model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm starting with Ember, and I wanted to know if its possible to do this.

My server model of a book:

```
Book = { 
    name: 'string',
    author_id: 'number' 
}
```

But in my Ember side, I wanted to have something like this:

```
Book = { 
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('author' , {via: 'author_id'})
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You don't define that on the relationship though, you implement transformation behavior in your serializer. So rather than telling Ember that your server calls that relationship something different, you just convert the relationship to the format Ember wants before it's loaded into the store.

For instance, if you're using the [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html), you can override the [keyForRelationship](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_keyForRelationship) hook.

```
App.BookSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    keyForRelationship: function(key) {
        if (key === 'author') {
            return 'author_id';
        } else {
            return key;
        }
    }
});
```

This will tell the serializer to get the data for the `author` relationship from the `author_id` field in your JSON. It'll also ensure that when it sends JSON back to your server, it converts the `author` relationship back to the `author_id` property when serializing.

If you're not using the RESTSerializer, you can probably find the serializer you're using on the [Ember Data API documentation page](http://emberjs.com/api/data/) and your serializer will mostly likely have the same method or a very similar method.

Comment: For completeness, here's how ActiveModelAdapter does it to be generic: https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter/blob/master/addon/active-model-serializer.js#L131-L140

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, I used the ActiveModelAdapter solution.